# Cabal never updates

Tags: cabal, cabal-install

I'm trying to update Cabal on OSX (with ghci 7.8.2 installed), so I run the following commands

```
cabal update
cabal install cabal-install
```

To get it up to date, and the installation seems to complete with no errors. However, when I run `cabal update` again, it still says that I'm not up to date and to run `cabal install cabal-install` again.

I've read that I might have to do something to make the new version of Cabal have precedence over the one installed with Haskell, but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to add `/Users/username/Library/Haskell/bin`
 to `$PATH` to get the latest version to be used.